# ReactSelector can not access all components

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

i am new to React and Testcafe and have to write some end-to-end tests. I thougt, it was a good idea to mainly use the ReactSelector from 'testcafe-react-selectors', but i can not access all components although they are accessible via the 'React Developer Tools' Components view in the DevTools of the browser (edge).

Can anyone give me a hint as to why this is the case?

best regards
sebastian

Comment: Can't help you without reproducing the problem, please add required information and sample code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hello, since i do not know what the problem is, i could not create an example with which this can be reproduced.

But it seems that i can only access components via ReactSelector, that have their own export in a component module. Some components are anonymous or embedded into others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found the issue: the elements, that i can't select, are *forwardref*s. It is an [already known bug](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-react-selectors/issues/144) in `testcafe-react-selectors`

It seems that there is a workaround in using `ReactSelector('WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField))')` instead of `ReactSelector('TextField')`.

I'm not sure, if this is really a good way to do this, so i ditched the *react-selectors* and now use only `data-testids`.

Answer (score 1):

I need to reproduce the problem locally to be able to assist you. If you manage to create a sample project, please create an issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository and add it there together with the information required to reproduce the incorrect behavior.